# how to use predict_on_batch to avoid out of GPU memory error with datagenerator

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, ram, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Keras model which consists of two parts (left and right), both working generally independently (due to a practical scenario), but these parts exchange some latent data generated by the model in intermediate steps. I want to compress this latent data using autoencoders. Therefore, I introduced autoencoders into the model as additional submodels.
For the training of these autoencoders, I generated submodels of the main model using calls similar to

```
    submodel = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[model.input], outputs=[model.get_layer(submodel_name).output])
```

This is working fine. However, I now generate the latent data, which I need to train my autoencoders using an L2 loss, by predicting the entire dataset:

```
    train = submodel.predict(train_ds)
```

However, because the original dataset is not that small, and because the submodels output dimension is rather large, I run out of GPU memory when running this line for one of my submodels.
The entire process of training the autoencoder is the following:

```
 submodel = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[model.input], outputs=[model.get_layer(submodel_name).output])
    AE_name = 'AE_' + submodel_name
    AE = model.get_layer(AE_name)
    
    train = submodel.predict(train_ds)        
    valid = submodel.predict(valid_ds)
    
    AE.bypass = False
    AE.compile(loss='mse', run_eagerly=False)

    AE.fit(x=train,y=train, validation_data=(valid,valid),
                    epochs=epochs, verbose=0, callbacks = [callbacks[0]])
```

Initially, to generate the data, the autoencoders were set to bypass (1:1 mapping), so that I use get the correct latent data of the original model without autoencoders.

How can I split the prediction and fit into smaller steps so that not that much GPU Ram is needed?
My issue is, that I am rather unfamiliar with the tensorflow Datagenerator class used to generate the training and validation data. My attempts so far failed.

To give context, the datagenerator, which is used to create train_ds and valid_ds, uses the following functions to encode and (subsequently) fetch the data:

```
    def fetch(self):
        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(self.tfr).map(self._decode,
                                                        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
        if self.mode == "train":
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(2000, reshuffle_each_iteration=False) 
            train_dataset = dataset.batch(1, drop_remainder=True)#dataset.batch(self.batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
            train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
            return train_dataset
        
        if self.mode == "valid":
            valid_dataset = dataset.batch(1, drop_remainder=False)
            valid_dataset = valid_dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE) 
            return valid_dataset
        
        else:
            dataset = dataset.batch(1, drop_remainder=True)
            dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
            return dataset

    def _encode(self, mode):                 
        writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(self.tfr)
        
        if self.mode != "test":
            mix_filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.wav_dir, "*mixed*.wav"))
            target_filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.wav_dir, "*target*.wav"))
            sys.stdout.flush()  
            
            for mix_filename, target_filename in tqdm(zip(mix_filenames, 
                                                          target_filenames), total = len(mix_filenames)):
                mix, _ = librosa.load(mix_filename, self.sample_rate, mono = False)
                clean, _ = librosa.load(target_filename, self.sample_rate, mono = False)
    
                def write(a, b):
                    example = tf.train.Example(
                        features=tf.train.Features(
                            feature={
                                "noisy_left" : self._float_list_feature(mix[0, a:b]),
                                "noisy_right": self._float_list_feature(mix[1, a:b]),
                                "clean_left" : self._float_list_feature(clean[0, a:b]),
                                "clean_right": self._float_list_feature(clean[1, a:b])}))
                    
                    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
                
                now_length = mix.shape[-1]
                target_length = int(self.duration * self.sample_rate)
    
                if now_length < target_length:
                    continue 
                
                stride = int(self.duration * self.sample_rate)
                for i in range(0, now_length - target_length, stride):
                    write(i, i + target_length)
```

I tried to iterator through train_ds and to call the model (not predict) on each element independently, the idea being that I train the autoencoder with each individual prediction for one epoch. However, I noticed that model(SingleElement) yields a very slightly (order of 10⁻5) difference to the model output when I call model.predict. The reason might be some normalization layer used (there is no dropout at work, I checked). Because I do not want to risk missing these model details (I got the code from a colleague), I'd prefer to avoid this approach and to somehow predict on batches. However, this I was not able to get to work.

Comment: If you can get it through with the batch size 1, as in your last snippet, try increasing the batch size until it runs OOM then back-off. There should be no allocations _during_ training, if it starts, it's gonna finish. But, generally, you need a GPU with a larger GRAM. Your time doing this contortionist's calisthenics is more expensive to the company in any case.

Comment: I do not understand, it is dying here "train = submodel.predict(train_ds)" are you saying in this line "            train_dataset = dataset.batch(1, drop_remainder=True)" I should increase the batchsize from 1 to X? How would this affect the "train = submodel.predict(train_ds)" line? I agree regarding the larger GRAM, but currently I have to work with that (I got 24 GB already)

Comment: The dataset consists of 6000 files, each 4 second long stereo audio sampled at 8 khz. The output of the RNN has dim of 512, so I am dealing with 3999 * 6000 * 2 ch * 512 floats, where the 3999 arise due to the encoder. This is about 22 GB. It can be done, if I manage to iteratively predict.

Comment: You have freedom in the choice of batch size. If the 4-second file must be processes as a unit (e.g., a TDNN), you may save memory (and possibly retain high parallelism, since TDNN is “ridiculously parallelizable” in itself) by reducing batch size. If you're recurrent, think of rearranging axes such that RNN processes only a limited number of audio samples, in a limited parallelism, and carry over it's output state to the next batch, same axis. GRU has a smaller output carry-over state, than LSTM, but generally it's ~ number of units. So no, my idea is work with _smaller_ batches, not larger.

Comment: Another option, if it's the preprocessing pipeline and not the model which wants too much GPU ram, you may place preprocessing only on the CPU. 56 Xeon cores are not a joke compared to e.g. T4 GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by switching to the CPU for the RAM intensive task. It is considerably slower, but in my case not too slow, so I can spare the time. I switched to CPU using

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    TrainModelOnLargeData
```